# A simple news bar showing messages from Twitter

Tags: php, api, twitter

I tried to read Twitter API but I'm a newbie and I found it really difficult. What I'd like to acheive is "simple": a news bar to add on my site showing messages I post on my Twitter account, with the date I posted them, like: "08/26 Text | 08/25 Text" and so on. The default ones are too big and with too many informations, I just need a very simple text-only one. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this can probably be done more easily by using the users timeline feed, such as `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=username`

I have a super simple example that uses the following and displays it using an AJAX news-scroller type effect over on [GitHub](https://github.com/johnernaut/Twitter-Feed).  Feel free to use it and modify it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for this effect

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

You also might want to check this simple to integrate Twitter jQuery library

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

. . . let me know if you need more help to get started